# innerHTML in DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml

I am unable to change the text inside my 'p' tag using this script

```
 <script>
 var firstItem = document.getElementByTagName('p');
 firstItem.innerHTML = 'Adding Javascript';
 </script>
```

Comment: Are you seeing any console errors?

Comment: it should be `getElementsByTagName` then `firstItem[0].innerHTML = 'Adding Javascript';`

Comment: No, it still isn't correct. @jfriend00 shows the correct way to do it

Comment: [Learn how to debug JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several coding errors.  Here's some corrected code:

```
 <script>
 var firstItem = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
 firstItem.innerHTML = 'Adding Javascript';
 </script>
```

1. The correct method is `document.getElementsByTagName('p')`.  Note the "s" at the end of "Elements".
2. Then, because `document.getElementsByTagName('p')` returns an HTML collection object, you have to either iterate over the collection or reach into the collection to grab a specific DOM object (which I did in my example with `[0]`).

And here's a working code snippet:

```js
// change just the first <p> tag
document.getElementById("test1").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var firstItem = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
    firstItem.innerHTML = 'Adding Javascript';
});

// change all the <p> tags
document.getElementById("test2").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var items = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      items[i].innerHTML = 'Setting All Items';
    }
});
```

```html
<button id="test1">Change text of first item</button><br><br>
<button id="test2">Change text of all items</button><br><br>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is more text</p>
<p>This is and more text</p>
```

Comment: Your answer has been very helpful. But what if I want to change the text of all the p elements in my HTML.

Comment: @AaravYadav - I added an example of changing all the `<p>` tags to the code snippet above.

Comment: I recently joined Stack Overflow, and its already being very helpful.

Comment: @AaravYadav - Glad this worked for you.  Since you're new to Stackoverflow, I might point out that if you get your question answered, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark next to the best answer.  That will also earn you and the person who provided the answer some reputation points which can lead to more privileges on the site.